# Solving a Recurrence with a Summation of Exponents as a Term

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, exponential-sum

This is totally a homework problem, but it's due in 27 minutes so I know I won't get anything in time for that. I don't want the answer, I just want to learn the technique. I've started a MS program but it's been over 30 years since my calculus classes.

I'm trying to solve the following recurrence:

$$
T(n) = 3T({n \over 2}) + 8n, \ T(1) = 1\ and \ n=2^k
$$

I have gotten to this point, and cannot get any further despite my most frenetic Googling:

$$
T(n) = 3^k + 8 \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} 3^j {n \over 2^j}
$$

The lectures for the class and all the other videos or pages I've found have either eliminated the initial exponential term completely and/or only have a simple exponential in the summation term (which is then solvable as a geometric summation).

It's now 16 minutes until deadline, but I still want to understand this so any pointers appreciated.

Randy

Comment: If your formula for $T(n)$ is correct, the sum is actually of a geometric series: $8n(3/2)^j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T(2^k) = 3T(2^{k-1}) + 8 \cdot2^k \tag{1}$$
$$T(2^{k-1}) = 3T(2^{k-2}) + 8 \cdot2^{k-1}\tag{2}$$
$$T(2^{k-2}) = 3T(2^{k-3}) + 8 \cdot2^{k-2}\tag{3}$$

$(3)$ in $(2) \implies$
$$T(2^{k-1}) = 3^2T(2^{k-3}) + 3 \cdot8 \cdot2^{k-2} + 8 \cdot2^{k-1} \tag{4}$$

$(4)$ in $(1) \implies$
$$T(2^k) = 3(3^2T(2^{k-3}) + 3 \cdot8 \cdot2^{k-2} + 8 \cdot2^{k-1}) + 8 \cdot2^k$$

Or, $$T(2^k) = 3^3T(2^{k-3}) + 3^2 \cdot8 \cdot2^{k-2} + 3 \cdot 8 \cdot2^{k-1} + 8 \cdot2^k$$

If you repeatedly substitute, ultimately you'll have

$$T(2^k) = 3^kT(2^{k-k}) + 8(3^{k-1}\cdot2^1 + 3^{k-2} \cdot 2^2 + \ldots + 3^{k-k} \cdot2^k) = 3^k + 8 \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}3^j 2^{k-j}$$

Or, $$T(2^k) = 3^k +  8 \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} 3^j \frac{n}{2^j}$$

Answer (score 2):

As

$$
T\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right)=3T\left(2^{\log_2\left(\frac n2\right)}\right)+8n
$$

calling now $\mathcal{T}\left(\cdot\right) = T\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_2 n$ we have the linear recurrence

$$
\mathcal{T}\left(z\right)=3\mathcal{T}\left(z-1\right)+2^{z+3}
$$

and solving this recurrence we got

$$
\mathcal{T}\left(z\right)=3^{z-1}c_0+2^4(3^z-2^z)
$$

and now going backwards with $z = \log_2 n$ we recover

$$
T\left(n\right) = 3^{\log_2 n-1}(3\cdot 2^4+c_0)-2^4n
$$